# decimal values in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, rounding, floor, ceil

How to display a value as follows in oracle:

99.99 as 99.9900,
99.9  as 99.9000,
 9.99 as  9.9900,
99    as 99.0000

All cases should be satisfied..
Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Use the format character `0`:

```
SQL> SELECT x, to_char(x, '99.0000')
  2  FROM (SELECT 99.99 x FROM dual
  3        UNION ALL SELECT 99.9 FROM dual
  4        UNION ALL SELECT 9.99 FROM dual
  5        UNION ALL SELECT 99 FROM dual);

         X TO_CHAR(X,'99.0000')
---------- --------------------
     99,99  99.9900
      99,9  99.9000
      9,99   9.9900
        99  99.0000
```

You will find all format options in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **TO_CHAR** function, with a format argument:

```
select to_char(99.99, '99.9999') from dual;
```